# Prevent escaping of JSON-String for GET-Request

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm trying to send json requests to an api in the following manner:

```
import json
import urllib.request

def listDevices():

        requestData = {
                "query": "requestDeviceList", 
                "id": "012345", 
                "action": "get", 
                "IMEIList": ["123","124"],
            }
        url = "https://example.com/api?" + json.dumps(requestData)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        return response
```

When I look at the access log on the server I get an error 400 (bad request):

```
"GET /api?{\"id\": \"012345\"," 400 300 "-" "-"
```

If I just paste the url and json in my browser without the escaped quotes everything works fine but I can't get rid of the escaped quotes.

Any suggestions on how to do this properly?

Comment: What does the api you are using actually expect? A query string that contains json directly would be very unusual. More likely would be that you send it a POST request with the json data in the body.

Comment: It is a query string directly containing json. The guy who did this did a few unusual things here and should stick to embedded stuff :/

Comment: Have you tried `url = "https://example.com/api?" + urllib.parse.quote(json.dumps(requestData))`

Comment: Now I have and it worked. Thank you.